# Delegated Authentication Login in Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, soap-api, delegated-authentication

I've to create a Delegated Authentication in Salesforce with LDAP. I've the POST call with the generated token (I've used [Axiomsso Herokuapp](https://axiomsso.herokuapp.com/GenerateToken.action)) that return me the SID:

```
POST: https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/52

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
      <n1:username>USER_HERE</n1:username>
      <n1:password>PASSWORD/TOKEN_HERE</n1:password>
    </n1:login>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Well now I have two questions:

1. How can I redirect user in Salesforce after do the POST call?
2. What LDAP has to do with the exported Salesforce WSDL? Just import it and put the @RestResource(urlMapping='/server') annotation in the generated class, and use it in Salesforce for the Delegated Gateway URL?

Thanks.

Comment: 1.Login Flow 2. Your delegated authentication service that will talk LDAP has to implement the interface described by WSDL. See [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_delauthentication_configuring.htm&type=5)

Comment: Why a Login Flow? The user will click a url/button on their intranet, I thought about doing a redirect with: "https://<endpoint host>/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=<session id>" with the data from the SOAP call

Comment: Ah, that kind of redirect. They'll be logged in already, you won't need `frontdoor.jsp`